# valueerror: time data does not match dataframe of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, runtime-error

df having data as below in pandas

```
"val1" 6972.75 01-AUG-18 08.11.51.319 AM
"val2" 6974.25 01-OCT-18 08.12.22.322 AM
```

I am using the code

`pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], format="%d-%m-%Y %H.%M.%S.%f")`

when i am running the code its giving error below

```
ValueError: time data '01-AUG-18 08.11.51.319 AM' does not match format '%d-%b-%Y %H.%M.%S.%f' (match)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format is all messed up. You used the incorrect format for the month and year and you can deal with the AM/PM with `%p`. (Most of the formats can be found under the [`datetime` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```
%b  #Month as locale’s abbreviated name: [Jan, Feb, …, Dec (en_US)]
%y  #Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number: [00, 01, …, 99]
%p  #Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM: [AM, PM (en_US)]
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': ['01-AUG-18 08.11.51.319 AM', 
                            '01-OCT-18 08.12.22.322 AM']})

pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], format="%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p", errors='coerce')
#0   2018-08-01 08:11:51.319
#1   2018-10-01 08:12:22.322
#Name: TIME, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have extra `AM` at the end. Try stripping it out:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'].str[:-3], format="%d-%m-%Y %H.%M.%S.%f")
```

Or **safer** is to include the format directive for them:

```
# notice the extra %p
pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], format="%d-%m-%Y %H.%M.%S.%f %p")
```

Or just let pandas guess, which is simpler but takes longer to run:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], dayfirst=True)
```

Comment: ```dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: 01-NOV-18 08.11.51.319 AM
``` its giving different errors